# Show that $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$ is an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, group-actions

I'd like to show that $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$ is a variety.  Is it even true that $\mathbb{H} = \{ x + iy : y > 0 \}$ is an algebraic variety?  There's no metric, so it's just the half of the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Do we have that $\{ q \in \mathbb{Q} : q > 0\}$ is a variety?   We have that $\{ xy = 1 \} \subset \mathbb{A}^2$ is a variety, and there's a group action such as $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,-y)$ preserving that curve.

Then we have the group action of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (which are integer-valued matrices) - is the quotient space of an algebraic variety another one?

I'd like to be able to say that $\big[\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}\big](\mathbb{Q})$ is a variety over $K = \mathbb{Q}$ and discuss the rational points.

---

Depending on which theorems we admit the problem is straightfoward. It's well-known that a [modular curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_curve) is an algebraic curve.

We know this is an instance of a **[Shimura Variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimura_variety)**.  This is like assuming the result we want to prove. See also: [Hilbert modular surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_modular_surface),

Comment: $\Bbb{H}$ is not an affine algebraic variety, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573509/prove-that-the-upper-half-plane-of-cartesian-plane-is-not-an-affine-variety). Pete Clark says more in his answer to [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21755/is-there-a-schemetical-construction-for-modular-curves-over-the-rationals/21758#21758).